# Grammatical usage of relative pronoun: "many people came who were interested in art"

Tags: relative-clauses, inversion

I'm confused by this sentence:

> many people came who were interested in art

Why is **who** is used after **came**? Is it correct?

Comment: here "who" is related to the people intrested in arts.

Answer (score 12):

The normal form of this sentence would be

> Many people who were interested in art came.

But sentences like that can be hard to understand, because the long relative clause *who were interested in art* keeps the listener/reader waiting for the main verb *came*.

In some circumstances English allows the components to be swapped, to keep the "light" verb phrase close to its subject, before the "heavy" modifier. That is what has happened to your example.

This is sometimes called  [heavy component extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition).

Answer (score 1):

From the sentence

> many people came who were interested in art

the reader primarily gets the impression that "many people came". However the part about their interest in art seems to be of secondary importance.

The suggested answer of

> Many people who were interested in art came.

is better because it still conveys that many people came, but the reader already knows that they are also people who were interested in art. Both parts of the information are clear.

In my opinion the sentence itself isn't particularly good. It would make more sense to also mention *what* the people were attending, to add context, e.g.

> The event was attended by many people who were interested in art.

Comment: That does make sense, but now you're using passive voice, which may or may not convey the right tone.  Perhaps "The event's audience included many people who..."?

Comment: I disagree. The main verb is _came_, so that is what the sentence is about, whatever order it is spoken in. The relative clause identifies or characterises the people, whether it precedes or follows. The extraposed version is just as clear, and avoids the processing overhead of remembering the incomplete main sentence while dealing with the subordinate clause. And whether the sentence is OK on its own or not depends entirely on the context: in some contexts your final suggestion may be right, in others it is unnecessary verbiage.